# Youtube - Channel theme-ing/skin-ing sandbox/staging mode

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

Trying to theme/skin a Youtube channel.

Is there a sandbox/staging mode? Or is it once you do, you have to publish?

Trying to get our QA to take a look at the new theme before publishing it.
Or if anyone knows of a better workflow, please let me know too.

Thank you,
Tee